# Cloning repositories from github fails

Tags: windows, git, github

I am unable to clone any repositories from github. I always get this error message

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the
correct access rights and the repository exists
```

I have taken care of the following :

1. Set my path variable to `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd; and C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;`
2. I have generated the public key and linked `id_rsa.pub` with git

I have seen all the related links and am unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Have you added your public key to your GitHub account? https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0):

If you have issue with the ssh key, you can at least use as a workaround [https url](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use):

```
git clone https://github.com/username/reponame
```

Regarding ssh, make sure that:

- environment variable `HOME` is defines, and that your private/public ssh keys are in:

  ```
  %HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa
  %HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
  ```
- your [public ssh key is added to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github).

Comment: I have added the public key to my git hub account, I also tried the https url and set the environment variabl HOME. I am still getting the same error and am unable to clone any repositories.

To give you a better idea , i am using Windows 8 and GitBash, Also with ssh -T git@github.com i get successfully authenticated , but am unable to clone later.

Comment: @MuffadalDaginawala can you give us an example of a git clone and its output message? Can you try it in a git cmd session (instead of a git bash)?

Comment: here is an example using https and ssh

Muffadal@MUFFADAL ~ (master)
$ git clone https://github.com/username/reponam
Cloning into 'reponame'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Muffadal@MUFFADAL ~ (master)
$ git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git
Cloning into 'reponame'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Simply make sure to test that in a cmd session as well, not just in a git bash session